Why did God Punish the Men of the Concubine of Givah for the Idol of Micha? God Exonerated Micha for Reasons That They Knew of!
Sanhedrin 103b:

בִּקְּשׁוּ מַלְאֲכֵי הַשָּׁרֵת לְדוֹחְפוֹ אָמַר לָהֶן הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא 'הַנִּיחוּ לוֹ שֶׁפִּתּוֹ מְצוּיָה לְעוֹבְרֵי דְּרָכִים' וְעַל דָּבָר זֶה 'נֶעְנְשׁוּ אַנְשֵׁי פִּלֶגֶשׁ בַּגִּבְעָה אָמַר לָהֶן הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא 'בִּכְבוֹדִי לֹא מְחִיתֶם עַל כְּבוֹדוֹ שֶׁל בָּשָׂר וָדָם מְחִיתֶם
The ministering angels sought to dismiss him (Micha) from the world. The Holy One, Blessed be He, said to them: Leave him, as his bread is available for travelers. And it is for this matter, the sin of Micah’s idol, that the people involved in the incident of the concubine in Gibeah were punished. The tribes of Israel waged war with the tribe of Benjamin and forty thousand of them were killed. The Holy One, Blessed be He, said to them: You did not protest for My honor and took no action to destroy Micah’s idol, but you protested for the honor of one of flesh and blood who was killed? Therefore, the other tribes were initially unsuccessful, and many of their soldiers were killed.

The Maharsha:

ועד"ז נענשו כו'. ר"ל שזה הדבר שהיה פתו מצויה לעוברי דרכים הטעה את אנשי ישראל במעשה פלגש בגבעה שלא מיחו במיכה ובאו לעונש כזה שנפלו מהם מ' אלף
Meaning that this matter that 'his bread is available for travelers' misled the Men of Israel in the matter of the concubine of Givah in that they did not protest against Micha and thus they came to the punishment of losing 40,000 men.

There is an obvious question - If God exonerated Micha due to 'his bread is available for travelers' and told the angels to let him be, why would God exact punishment from Israel who were also aware that Micha's bread was available for travelers and thus let him be?
Two solid approaches have come to my attention:
a. God can waive God's honor, but humans cannot waive God's honor (even if mitigating circumstances - 'his bread is available for travelers'- are involved). It's God's call to decide if a merit will mitigate against an act that violates His honor. This is NOT our call to make.
b. It's the inconsistency that's the problem. They took a casual approach to God's honor - emulating God's approach - but became interventionist and angry in the face of a human atrocity (that could have been handled differently). Something we can call selective tolerance/vigilantism. In other words, they failed to search for alternatives/mitigating circumstances during Pilegesh B'givah!
Are there other answers?

R' Gershon Weiss in the book Shimshon's Struggle. The Era of Shoftim: Pesel Micha, Pilegesh b'Givah gives another reason after suggesting inconsistent behavior of the tribes (your item b.) on pp. 298 - 300. He writes:

Although the action of "removing evil from Yisrael" was good, the people carrying out the action were not good enough. The Bnei Yisrael considered themselves perfectly righteous and thought that the Benjamites were not. They demanded that (shevet) Binyamin deal with Pilegesh b'Givah when they themselves had failed to deal with the Idol of Michah. Before undertaking to purify Binyamin of its sin, the Bnei Yisrael should have purified themselves of their own sins. As it is said in Yalkut Me'am Loez (no exact location given):
Whenever a person criticizes, rebukes, or punishes another for some misbehavior, Hashem checks the first person's record to see whether he himself has behaved properly.

